# How to execute LINQ query for dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I've got dictionary which contains IDs as string and cities name also as string.
I want to find city by it's name and return ID. There's my code:

```
public string GetIdByCityName(string name)
{
    if (Cities.ContainsValue(name))
    {
        return Cities
            .Select(x => x)
            .Where(v => v.Value == name)
            .Select(k => k.Key)
            .ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Cities is of course my dictionary. I have a problem, because this code is not working. I tried to use debugger and I found what value has been returned from method:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator
>   2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
>   2[System.String,System.String],System.Boolean]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have a dictionary then try this :             Dictionary<string, string> Cities = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string city = Cities.Where(x => x.Value == "City Name").FirstOrDefault().Key;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see this result, because `.Select(k => k.Key)` is a LINQ query, which has type of `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`. It's not a single string. When you apply `ToString()` to the type of query, you see the name of the type.

You can pick the first one entry which matches given name:

```
 return Cities.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == name).Select(kvp => kvp.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note: several cities can have same names. Also you don't need to do `.Select(x => x)` because it's projects entry to self.

Comment: @IvanStoev good catch, thanks. I have forgot that it's a struct

Comment: Simply taking the first result is possibly not correct. If there are multiple cities with the same name, you will not notice that (because you always get the first one).

Comment: @S.Spindler Your concern was noted at the bottom of his answer.

Comment: Since the default for a string is `null`, and they wanted an empty string, that line should end with `?? String.Empty;`

Comment: @JamesCurran yes, that would be the simplest option.

Answer (score 3):

> The shortest amount of code (and possibly easier to read) would be:
>
> ```
> return Cities.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Value == name).Key;
> ```

---

#### Simplified Method

Your method could also be simplified to

```
public string GetIdByCityName(string name)
{
    return Cities.ContainsValue(name) ?
        Cities.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Value == name).Key : String.Empty;
}
```

or if you are using C#7 you can do this fancy thing ([null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator))

```
string GetIdByCityName(string name)
{
    return Cities.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Value == name).Key ?? String.Empty;
}
```